# Can access privilege statements be executed inside a transaction?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have SQL access privilege scripts running each day against our Snowflake subscription: `GRANT`, `REVOKE` ...

Can they be executed into a transaction to avoid interrupting our services?

Thanks,
Christophe

Comment: Please add examples of code to the question for better understanding. Showing with a code snippet would support your question of what you want to achieve. If you want to enclose GRANT/REVOKE statements inside a transaction block that is fully supported in Snowflake and can be done.

Comment: Thanks Zonera, you fully answered my question as I want to enclose GRANT/REVOKE statements in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Zonera in previous comment:

> If you want to enclose GRANT/REVOKE statements inside a transaction block that is fully supported in Snowflake and can be done.